# Cache images jquery/javascript globaly

Tags: jquery, html, rss

I have an `ASP.NET MVC` based website witch manages the database content and generate `RSS` files with `View`. But for output I use simple static `HTML` pages witch downloads content with a `js` file as code in blew:

```
$.get(RssRoot + '/instruments',function(datas){
$('item',datas).each(function(i) {
    var name = $(this).find("name").text();
    var thumbnail = $(this).find("thumbnail").text();
    var id = $(this).find("id").text();
    var href = Root + '/instrument.html?id=' + id;
    $("#instrument").append('<a href="' + href + '"><img title="' + name + '" class="image" src="' + thumbnail + '" /></a>');
});
});
```

Thumbnails are generating using this code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Instrument(Guid? Id = null)
{
    if (Id == null) return HttpNotFound();
    return File(db.Instruments.Find(Id).Thumbnail, "image/png");
}
```

You can see that images are not ftp files. They are loading from database. For example a thumbnail `url` for browser: `~/Thumbs/Instruments/fdbc870e-87a4-4d6e-befa-027af647f4ca`

As you now, because this way has a behavior like `lazy loading`, I used it. But it has some problems such as downloading images every time. How can I cache images in browser for next use?

***Note:*** I know that there are lots of plugins ready; But because my project is not standard as I said, this challenge is with it.

***Why?*** I wanna reduce my database server traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to improve performance, consider adding the items to the `<system.webserver>` node of your web.config. These will enable object compression and cache static objects for 7 days:

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
            <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
            <dynamicTypes>
                <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/javascript; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
            </dynamicTypes>
            <staticTypes>
                <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/javascript; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
            </staticTypes>
        </httpCompression>
        <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true">
        </httpProtocol>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
            <!-- IF PAGE STOPS LOADING CORRECTLY, REMOVE THE FOLLOWING MIME TYPE DEFINITIONS TO DEBUG -->
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
        </staticContent>
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention my friend. I have an unprofessional hosting service witch gives my 25GB per month for data transfer. 100MB for files and unlimited for database. So I upload my images to database. But my 25GB is reducing fast. So I need to force browser to cache images. You can see app [here](http://alvand-orchestra.ir/fa/index.html).